# FastApi how to find where HTTPException is raised

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm working on a new FastApi  project written by other programmers. one api is raising a Httpexception and i can not find the specific location. what is an easy way to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easies way is to add a general Exception handler to catch all exceptions, print the traceback and raise it again.

main.py:

```
import traceback

@app.exception_handler(HTTPException)
async def http_exception_handler(request: Request, exc:HTTPException):
    print(traceback.print_tb(exc.__traceback__))
    raise exc
```